# Method '~' of object '~' failed in vb6 with Excel

Tags: excel, vb6

We are facing a issue with one of our VB 6.0 application.
There is line of code which convert a text file to excel file through Excel.Workbook.
This code works fine when we run through windows application.

But if we run the same exe from a windows service developed in C#.Net then it gives this error on this line

```
oWB.SaveAs FileName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8
```

I have tried to search on google but didn't get any success.

Any suggestion will be very much helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
AR

Comment: there is no need to regards

Answer (score 1):

While not an answer to your specific question, you might consider:

[Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/257757)

> **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

The bold text is bold in the article.

Basically you aren't supposed to even attempt what you are doing.